# What is the difference between SlugField() vs CharField() in Django models

Tags: django, django-models

So, in my Django projects, I made my model to be like the following

```
class Store(models.Model):
    domainKey = models.CharField()
```

I had the above to make each store has its own domain like the following

```
www.domain.com/my-name-is-django
```

Anyway, it was perfectly working fine. But, I just found out `SlugField()` which is used for the same purpose as what I did in above.
My question is why we need to use SlugField() because I implemented the same thing without `SlugField()`. Is there its own any feature that `CharField()` doesn't have?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why SlugField() in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495299/why-slugfield-in-django)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/427160/5644965

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**A slug** is a string without special characters, in lowercase letters and with dashes instead of spaces, optimal to be used in URLs. An example of slug could be:

```
 example/this-is-a-slug/150
```

you can look for more information here [Documentation django slug](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#slugfield)

**CharField** has max_length of 255 characters , and accept special characters.

[About CharField Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#charfield)